# Enthalpy of formation of the oxygen molecule

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to obtain the enthalpy of formation of the oxygen molecule .From the wikipedia table of enthalpies of compound formation, we can obtain the following values ​​for carbon dioxide and carbon monoxide (for $T=25^\circ C$):

**Carbon dioxide**:

1. $\Delta H_f^\circ$ (kJ/mol)= -393.52
2. J/mol=-393520

**Carbon monoxide**

3. $\Delta H_f^\circ$ (kJ/mol)=-110.53
4. J/mol=-110530

Are the above data sufficient to obtain the enthalpy of formation of the oxygen molecule?

Comment: Isn’t it zero???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite enough information. But the answer is simple, the heat of formation of each element is taken as zero. See probably any modern thermodynamics text. $Thermodynamics$ by W C Reynolds, (1965) on page 302 states "...by convention the elemental substances have zero enthalpy at the standard reference state..." So, $O_2$ is zero. From this you can find the heat generated by burning CO and half a mole of oxygen to carbon dioxide.